# Why does this piece of Golang code not work?

Tags: go

```
_, error := connection.Read(buffer)
buffer := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
splited := strings.Split(string(buffer), " ")
switch splited[0] {
case "TEST":
    connection.Write([]byte("TEST CONNECTION OK"))
    log.Printf("TEST COMMAND")
    break;
```

If I write "TEST" in client, the server will not enter the case statement. But if I send "TEST  SOMETHING" from client, the server will enter it as expected. Is this a bug of go-lang?

Comment: Why is there a `break` at the end of `case`? Go does not require it.

Comment: Ahh.. Just habit, maybe bad, got it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out your split buffer slice, it still contains the null bytes with which it was initialized:

http://play.golang.org/p/CW45hPBZ-e

```
buffer := make([]byte, 32)
copy(buffer, []byte("TEST"))

splited := strings.Split(string(buffer), " ")

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", splited)
```

Prints:
`[]string{"TEST\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"}`